# Node server cannot connect to Postgres through Docker, using TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, docker, typeorm

I'm currently building a system in Node with a Postgres db, and I've created a container using docker-compose for both. By running `docker-compose up` I manage to initialize all container (Node app, Postgres db and PGAdmin) and a connection is successfully established.

```
server      | yarn run v1.22.5
server      | $ ts-node-dev --respawn --ignore-watch node_modules src/index.ts
server      | [INFO] 14:35:39 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.4.3)
server      | Atempting to connect to database...
server      | SUCCESS: Connection achieved.
server      | Running migrations...
server      |  Running Server on port 3000
```

However when I try to generate migrations using `yarn typeorm migration:generate -n [something]` I get a `ENOTFOUND` error.

```
yarn run v1.22.15
$ node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n UserRefac
Error during migration generation:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'postgres'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    image: server
    build:
      context: .
      target: build-node
    volumes:
      - ./:/src/app
      - src/app/node_modules
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    entrypoint: ['yarn', 'start']
    networks:
      - servernet

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: inesc2021
      POSTGRES_USER: inesc
      POSTGRES_DB: db_inesc
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - servernet

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=inesc@inesc.pt
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=inesc2021
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - servernet
networks:
  servernet:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node as build-node

WORKDIR /src/app

COPY . .
RUN ["yarn"]
RUN ["yarn", "build"]
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn"]
```

This is my `ormconfig.json`:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "postgres",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "inesc",
  "password": "inesc2021",
  "database": "db_inesc",
  "synchronize": false,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["src/classes/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migrations/**/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/classes",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migrations"
  }
}
```

And finally, this is my `package.json`, so you can see how I define my scripts:

```
{
  "name": "ihanduapp_v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn --ignore-watch node_modules src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start2": "yarn build && node dist/index.js",
    "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.2",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.32.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.32.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-openapi-validator": "^4.13.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.1.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.37"
  }
}
```

Of course, when I change `"host": "postgres"` to `"host": "localhost"`, I'm **able to generate and run migrations** using the above-metioned yarn script, but I naturally **loose the connections between my containers**, the server app failing the retry logic.

I don't know where to problem lies, as I'm new both to docker-compose and TypeORM, so any help would be more than welcome.

As a final **NOTE**: I'm running all this in MacOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to run the migrate command on your host OS, which does not know about a host called `postgres`.

You will need to [run the migrate command within the app container](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) (which is in the virtual network that has a host called `postgres`):

```
docker-compose exec server node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n UserRefac
```

Comment: Beautifully (and embarrassingly) simples. Goes to show how much of a newbie I still am at these sort of things. Worked straight-of-the-box, like a charm! Thanks!